# NaNs produced when running summarySE

Tags: r

## Running summarySE on species vs density dataset

My dataset is;

```
1   1   Zeacumantus  8.2222220
2   2   Amphibola    1.2222220
3   3   Cominella    1.7777778
4   4   Zeacolpus    0.5555560
5   5   Cominella    0.0000000
6   6   Diloma       1.4444440
7   7   Haminoea     0.1111110
8   8   Austrovenus  82.0000000
9   9   Macomona     7.7777780
10  10  Nucula       0.6666670
11  11  Halicarcinus 0.4444444
12  12  Austrohelice 2.6666670
13  13  Hemiplax     1.4444440
14  14  Hemigrapsus  0.3333330
15  15  worm         6.8888890
16  16  Anthopleura  0.0000000
17  17  Paracaudina  0.222222
```

the code I am trying to run is

```r
library(Rmisc)

sum = summarySE(high, measurevar="density", groupvars = "species")
```

and it produces the error message

```r
Warning message:
In qt(conf.interval/2 + 0.5, datac$N - 1) : NaNs produced
```

I have run `which(is.nan())` for both "species" and "density" and both have produced `interger(0)`

Why is this happening?

Comment: The error is not saying that you have NAs in your dataset. It says that while trying to do that step, it produced NaNs.

Comment: `qt` will return `NaN` if you pass values outside the interval [0, 1] to its `p` parameter. I wonder why probabilities are calculated from a confidence interval but you don't show how you define `summarySE` or from which package you got it.

Comment: I got summarySE from "Rmisc", what do you mean by define?

Comment: @JacobBanks is this your whole dataset? Because calculating a standard deviation over 1 value doesn't make sense and produces NaNs. For example in the dataset you give the specie Amphibola only occurs once, so using your code and this exact input data I would be surprised if I didn't get NaNs.

Comment: Yes, if n equals 1 for a group, you calculate `qt(p, 0)` and the t-distribution is not defined for zero degrees of freedom.